# How to share constants across content and popup?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I have the following setup. When I include an `export` statement in `global_constants.js`I get an `unexpected token export` in `content.js`.

In `popup.js` I get an error for `unexpected {` for the line with my import statement.

And I've tried a bunch of other combinations and I can't seem to get my constants file to be accepted by both popup and content.

- global_constants.js

  ```js
  const URL_REGEX = new RegExp("foobar");
  ```
- popup/popup.html

  ```html
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="popup.css">

    <script type="module" src="../global_constants.js"></script>
    <script src="popup.js"></script>

  </head>
  ```
- popup/popup.js

  ```js
  import {URL_REGEX} from '../global_constants';
  ```
- mainfest.json

  ```js
  "content_scripts": [
      {
        "js": [
          "jquery-3.2.1.min.js", "global_constants.js", "content.js"
  ```

Comment: Sounds like https://crbug.com/738739. Apparently you'll have to use a bundler (at least during development). Or just use it as a normal ES5 script in both places.

Comment: It's actually just one of the constants that I need to share. I wanted to do it this way to keep my code nice and DRY. But that looks like known bug or a problem that's hard enough to solve that it's better to just include a comment to tell me to change both locations.